# In what form to keep a chat list and their messages in client side

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, chat, message

I have 2 options for storing the received data

  1.

```
[
 {
   chatId: 'chatId1',
   author: 'authorId1',
   members: [],
   messages: []
 },
{
   chatId: 'chatId2',
   author: 'authorId2',
   members: [],
   messages: []
 },
...
]
```

  2.

```
 {
   'chatId1':  {
               author: 'authorId1',
               members: [],
               messages: []
             },
    'chatId2':  {
               author: 'authorId2',
               members: [],
               messages: []
             },
     ...

 }
```

In the first option, to add a message in chat  with the `chatId2` ID, I have to loop and find the missing chat, but in the second option, I can get the `chatId2` property of an object. 
**What form do you recommend?**

P.S. Sorry for my English. Thanks ;)

Comment: An array will keep all objects in the order you put them in, whereas an object containing objects can become out of order, so your messages will be out of sync unless you put an index or timestamp on them for example but that won't be nice. So I recommend using an array and referencing them with: arr[index]. So chatId1 would actually be referenced by messages[0]. If you really want to reference them by a string like 'chatId0' then you can use a Map data structure which keeps them in order like an array so you can loop them in order, but you can also reference items by key such as 'chatId0'.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need to do, size of the data, requirements, etc.

You can easily combine these options by keeping the `id` field and looping though values if needed. But depending on your tasks you may also need to add additional sorting then.